# Moqui 1.4.1 Postgresql Configuration

Tags: postgresql, gradle, ubuntu-12.04, failed-installation, moqui

I am trying to get the Moqui 1.4.1 release up and running but using Postgres as the database platform. Here are the platform details.

---

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Postgres 9.4 using JDBC driver postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar (sitting in /runtime/lib. Hope that's the right place)

---

Firstly, I can't find MoquiDefaultConf.xml anywhere so I assume this is only applicable to development?

Under runtime/conf, I have MoquiDevConf.xml, MoquiDevTestConf.xml, MoquiProductionConf.xml, MoquiStagingConf.xml. In all four, I have added the following entity-facade entry.

```
    <entity-facade crypt-pass="MoquiDefaultPassword:CHANGEME">
      <!--
        <datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="postgresql" schema-name="">
        <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/MoquiDEFAULT?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" jdbc-username="moqui" jdbc-password="moqui" pool-minsize="2" pool-maxsize="50"/>
    </datasource>   
    -->

    <datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="postgres" schema-name="public">
      <!--
            <inline-jdbc pool-minsize="5" pool-maxsize="50">
                <xa-properties user="moqui" password="moqui" serverName="localhost" portNumber="5432"
                               databaseName="MoquiDEFAULT"/>
            </inline-jdbc>
        -->

        <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/MoquiDEFAULT"
                    jdbc-username="moqui" jdbc-password="moqui"
                    pool-minsize="2" pool-maxsize="50"/>
        </datasource>
        </entity-facade>

 <!-- end snippet -->
```

The Problem:

When I run gradle load, the load target

1. creates a bunch of derby databases which I don't understand given that it is now configured for Postgres.
2. The tables **enumeration_type** and **enumeration** are created in Postgres.

**Then the process gets stuck.**

Here is the output at the point.

```
    > --- 12304 [main] INFO org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDbMeta 
 Created table [ENUMERATION_TYPE] for entity [moqui.basic.EnumerationType]
    > --- 12788 [main] INFO org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDbMeta 
 Created table [ENUMERATION] for entity [moqui.basic.Enumeration]
    > --- 611953 [-task-scheduler] WARN Bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction 
 transaction timed out: a Bitronix Transaction with GTRID [3132372E302E312E3100000000002E270D00000001], status=MARKED_ROLLBACK, 1 resource(s) enlisted (started Thu Jan 01 02:50:24 SAST 1970)
```

So Bitronix isn't happy about something.

If I terminate the load and restart, then it creates the next table **geo** and then gets stuck again although this time, it doesn't show the Bitronix warning.

```
    > --- 12268    [main] INFO org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDbMeta 
 Created table [GEO] for entity [moqui.basic.Geo]
```

Help appreciated.

**Additional info in response to answers**:

I downloaded [this](https://github.com/moqui/moqui/releases/download/release-1.4.1/moqui-1.4.1.zip) for the purposes of assessing functionality so I just want to run the application not extend it. As you've pointed out, this only has the pre-built WAR file in it. However, if I browse the contents of the WAR file, I find no MoquiDefaultConf.xml file. In fact, the only XML file in the whole WAR file is web.xml.

Upon discovering this, and after reading the chapter in the book regarding setup, I googled MoquiDefaultConf.xml and found the file on github. I then copied the datasource element out of that and simply pasted that into the entity-facade of ALL the listed Moqui*Conf.xml to make sure it got picked up....which it finally did but with the halting issue. I tried both inline jdbc options; once with the one with the xa-properties tag and once with the one without.

Sorry. I am from a Microsoft background so this is all a bit foreign to me , but in my defence I was technically capable of getting OFBiz up and running by fumbling around like this.

**UPDATE**:

OK. Progress.

Turns out I was running Postgres 9.1 not 9.4 (Oops. Linux noob) with postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar driver. Not sure if that was contributing to the halting but I upgraded to Postgres 9.4 with postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar driver, and the halting was still happening.

David, you correctly pointed out the missing startup-add-missing and runtime-add-missing attributes. The reason this happened was because I had initially tried to cobble the datasource element together from OFBiz equivalent, and when I eventually found the MoquiDefaultConf.xml online, I only copied the inline-jdbc elements into the datasource elements I used from OFBiz and didn't copy the whole datasource element. Silly. Anyway, after adding the datasource element to ONLY the MoquiDevConf.xml and "gradle load"ing, 91 tables were created in Postgres so the build completed successfully....well sort of.

A derby database called MoquiDEFAULT is **still** created in the derby folder in the db folder. I can confirm that the webapp is talking to Postgres because I created an entry in the Example grid and it appeared in the example table in Postgres. I don't know enough about the internals to know if queries are duplicating on the derby database.

Lastly, after using a process of elimination, I determined that the build was using MoquiDevConfig.xml and not MoquiProductionConf.xml. I.e. when I put the datasource in only the MoquiProductionConf.xml entity-facade element, it has no effect and creates tables only in derby (well...over 100 .dat files) and none in Postgres. This is confusing given that MoquiInit.properties only ever references MoquiProductionConf.xml. I can confirm that building using MoquiDevConfig.xml generates about 20 fewer .dat files than does MoquiProductionConf.xml. I don't know enough about Gradle build files to know what to change.

MoquiDevConf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<tools enable-elasticsearch="true" enable-camel="false"/>

<cache-list>
    <!-- Development Mode - don't use these for production, load testing, etc.
         Cleared by default every 20 seconds from when loaded into cache. -->
    <cache name="entity.definition" expire-time-idle="30"/>
    <!-- longer timeout since this basically looks through all files to check for new or moved entity defs -->
    <cache name="entity.location" expire-time-idle="300"/>
    <cache name="entity.data.feed.info" expire-time-idle="30"/>

    <cache name="service.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="service.java.class" expire-time-idle="5"/>

    <cache name="kie.component.releaseId" expire-time-idle="5"/>

    <cache name="screen.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="screen.template.mode" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="screen.template.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>

    <cache name="resource.xml-actions.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="resource.groovy.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <!-- longer timeout because these are cached by the expression text itself, so changed text is a new entry -->
    <cache name="resource.groovy.expression" expire-time-idle="600"/>
    <cache name="resource.javascript.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>

    <cache name="resource.ftl.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="resource.gstring.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="resource.wiki.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="resource.markdown.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="resource.text.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>
    <cache name="resource.reference.location" expire-time-idle="5"/>

    <cache name="l10n.message" expire-time-idle="600"/>
</cache-list>

<server-stats stats-skip-condition="ec.web?.request?.pathInfo?.startsWith('/rpc') || ec.web?.request?.pathInfo?.startsWith('/status')">
    <!-- For development, track everything! It'll run slow through... -->
    <artifact-stats type="screen" persist-bin="true" persist-hit="true"/>
    <artifact-stats type="screen-content" persist-bin="true" persist-hit="true"/>
    <artifact-stats type="transition" persist-bin="true" persist-hit="true"/>
    <artifact-stats type="service" persist-bin="true" persist-hit="true"/>
    <artifact-stats type="service" sub-type="entity-auto" persist-bin="true" persist-hit="false"/>
    <artifact-stats type="service" sub-type="entity-implicit" persist-bin="true" persist-hit="false"/>
    <artifact-stats type="entity" persist-bin="true"/>
</server-stats>

<webapp-list>
    <webapp name="webroot" http-port="8080" https-enabled="false">
        <root-screen host=".*" location="component://webroot/screen/webroot.xml"/>
    </webapp>
</webapp-list>

<screen-facade boundary-comments="true">
    <!-- The default conf file has a macro location defined for html already, but this is an example of how to
        refer to a file to override the default macros. -->
    <screen-text-output type="html" mime-type="text/html"
                        macro-template-location="template/screen-macro/ScreenHtmlMacros.ftl"/>
</screen-facade>

<entity-facade crypt-pass="MoquiDefaultPassword:CHANGEME">
<datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="postgres" schema-name="public" startup-add-missing="true" runtime-add-missing="false">
    <inline-jdbc pool-minsize="5" pool-maxsize="50">
    <xa-properties user="moqui" password="moqui" serverName="localhost" portNumber="5432"
              databaseName="MoquiDEFAULT"/>
    </inline-jdbc>
    <!-- <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/MoquiDEFAULT"
        jdbc-username="moqui" jdbc-password="moqui" pool-minsize="2" pool-maxsize="50"/> -->
</datasource>
</entity-facade>

<repository-list>
    <!-- <repository name="main" location="http://localhost:8081/rmi" type="rmi" workspace="default"
                username="admin" password="admin"/> -->
</repository-list>
<component-list>
    <!-- This loads the tools component over top of the default one, which will result in a warning but works
        fine. Use something like this to refer to components in a JCR repository. -->
    <component name="tools" location="component/tools"/>
</component-list>
```

Comment: For the Derby databases, what are the databases you see created? Answers to the other questions below.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. Sorry. When I said "databases", I should have said ".dat files". There is only one db created called MoquiDEFAULT.

Comment: Apologies for the delays, and not sure why no one else picked this up. Stack Overflow doesn't have very reliable notification emails, and I only check the site every so often. As a general question for you: if you are trying to assess functionality, why not just run it on Derby?

Comment: About the XML files in the WAR file: even without adding the runtime directory to the WAR file (for easy upload to servers such as ElasticBeanstalk or deploying in a servlet container like Apache Tomcat), I just counted and there are 42 XML files in the framework-only WAR in the latest version of Moqui, and that hasn't changed in a while. That said, all of this is documented (on moqui.org web pages and in the Making Apps with Moqui book), and that is usually the easier way to get information.

Comment: Parsing through this question it looks like the last issue remaining is a question about why a Derby database is still created. Is that correct or did I miss something else? To answer that it would be helpful to see your full conf file (i.e. MoquiDevConf.xml from what you wrote). About the conf files: when you run from a gradle or ant build script it specifies the conf file to use explicitly, otherwise it uses the one in MoquiInit.properties (especially when dropping a WAR into Tomcat, etc). Either way, Moqui reports which conf file it is using on startup.

Comment: BTW, I am wondering about your entire conf file because my guess is you don't have a datasource defined for the tenantcommon entity group, so the entities in that group are still going into the Derby database. There are more details about groups and datasources for them in the docs too.

Comment: Hi David. Now worries about the delay. I appreciate you getting back to me.

OK. On the first issue, we are evaluating both functional and architectural capabilities so we are deploying to get an understanding of the enterprise scalability implications as well. We've deployed with OFBiz on Postgres to compare against as well.

Comment: I must be doing something utterly stupid because I download [this](https://github.com/moqui/moqui/releases/download/release-1.4.1/moqui-1.4.1.zip) and unzip it. Then I extract the WAR file using WinRAR and if I do a search through the entire folder, all that comes is web.xml. Are these other XML files encapsulated in the JAR files perhaps? I read Chapter 2 of the book and the stuff online when I started out but my comprehension appears to be lacking.

Apart from the mysterious missing WAR XML files, you are correct that the only issue left is why the load is creating a Derby database.

Comment: I will add the contents of my MoquiDevConf.xml to the OP so that you can see the contents.

Lastly, when all this is up and running nicely, I promise to make a nice neat answer for others. :) This thread has become a bit of a mess.

Comment: I added details about tenantcommon to my original answer, that should take care of your remaining Derby DB problem.

Answer (score 0):

The MoquiDefaultConf.xml file is in the pre-built executable war file if you downloaded the binary release, though you can see it here in the source repo:

https://github.com/moqui/moqui/blob/master/framework/src/main/resources/MoquiDefaultConf.xml

In there you will see an example configuration for Postgres:

```
    <datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="postgres" schema-name="public" startup-add-missing="true" runtime-add-missing="false">
        <inline-jdbc pool-minsize="5" pool-maxsize="50">
            <xa-properties user="moqui" password="moqui" serverName="localhost" portNumber="5432"
                           databaseName="MoquiDEFAULT"/>
        </inline-jdbc>
        <!-- <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/MoquiDEFAULT"
                jdbc-username="moqui" jdbc-password="moqui" pool-minsize="2" pool-maxsize="50"/> -->
    </datasource>
```

Note especially these two attributes on the datasource element: startup-add-missing="true" runtime-add-missing="false". Postgres does not support creating tables on the fly, so they all have to be created before the system gets running instead of the default mode which is to create tables only as they are needed (when the first write is done).

The MoquiDefaultConf.xml file also has a definition for the "tenantcommon" entity group, pointing it to Derby:

```
    <datasource group-name="tenantcommon" database-conf-name="derby" schema-name="MOQUI">
        <inline-jdbc pool-minsize="2" pool-maxsize="10">
            <xa-properties databaseName="${moqui.runtime}/db/derby/MoquiDEFAULT" createDatabase="create"/>
        </inline-jdbc>
    </datasource>
```

To put those entities in Postgres as well you'll need to add a similar definition to the Moqui Conf XML file used at runtime.

Comment: I downloaded [link](https://github.com/moqui/moqui/releases/download/release-1.4.1/moqui-1.4.1.zip) for the purposes of assessing functionality so I just want to run the application not extend it.

Comment: First time posting on SO too. So wasn't aware of timeout. Additional info in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use this config inside entity-facade tag in MoquiDevConf.xml or MoquiProductionConf.xml

```
<datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="postgres" schema-name="public" startup-add-missing="true" runtime-add-missing="false">
        <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/dbname" jdbc-username="postgres" jdbc-password="pass"/>
</datasource>
```